# Update text with jquery on socketIO event

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, socket.io

I have the following code to update the text inside a div on a socketIO message. The event is fired 10 times, and all the console.log show up fine, but the text in my div updates only once.

```
socket.on('jobMsg',function(msg){
  if(msg.type==='progress'){
    $('#'+msg.store).parent().text(msg.progress+' %');
    console.log(msg);
  }
});
```

The format of a msg is :

```
{type: "progress", store: "xxx", progress: 10}
```

Why does this happen (most important question)?
and, how do I fix this?

jade code for this bit, if it helps :

```
.monitor
  .led(id=res['store'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `$('#'+msg.store).parent().text('....')` targets the parent element and overwrites all and any content with the retrieved text, thus removing the `$('#xxx')` element completely, so the next time around there is no `$('#'+msg.store).parent()` as it was removed (not the parent, but the targeted element).

Change it to :

```
socket.on('jobMsg',function(msg){
  if(msg.type == 'progress') {
    $('#'+msg.store).text(msg.progress+' %');
  }
});
```

Comment: If i change the text of my parent element using its id, will it also remove the child?

Comment: Yes it will, text() and html() removes everything and replaces it with the string passed.

Comment: You can wrap the text in a span with an ID inside the parent, and then target that span instead.